# Разбивка пунктов списка на блоки в цикле

Tags: php

Привет всем! Просьба помочь со следующей задачей:

Мне нужно сделать разбивку пунктов(`li`) по `div`.

То есть, надо вывести 4 блока, в каждом из которых есть `li`.

На данный момент  выведены все пункты без разбивки.

Исходный код прилагаю:

```
<? foreach($arResult['SECTION'] as $section):?>
<div class='sitemap-block'>
 <h1 class="sitemap-title"><?=$section['NAME']?></h1>
 <ul class="sitemap">
  <?foreach($section['ITEMS'] as $item):?>
  <li>
    <a href="/catalog/programmnoe-obespechenie/filter/<?=strtolower($section['CODE'])?>-is-<?=$item['CODE']?>/apply/"><?=$item['NAME']?></a>
  </li>
  <?endforeach;?>
</ul>
</div>
<?endforeach;?>
```

. 
    [image: spisok]

Comment: Сформулируйте задачу нормально, Что сделать то надо? разбить список на 4 части и вывести в разные блоки? `array_chunk()` вам в помощью с двойным циклом.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Если я вас правильно понял, то должно получиться как то вот так:

```
<? foreach($arResult['SECTION'] as $section):?>
<div class='sitemap-block'>
 <h1 class="sitemap-title"><?=$section['NAME']?></h1>
 <ul class="sitemap">
  <? $items_blocks = array_chunk($section['ITEMS'], round(count($section['ITEMS'])/4));  ?>
  <?foreach($items_blocks as $items):?>
    <div>
      <?foreach($items as $item):?>
        <li>
          <a href="/catalog/programmnoe-obespechenie/filter/<?=strtolower($section['CODE'])?>-is-<?=$item['CODE']?>/apply/"><?=$item['NAME']?></a>
        </li>
      <?endforeach;?>
    </div>
  <?endforeach;?>
</ul>
</div>
<?endforeach;?>
```

Мы все итемы разбили на 4 массива и по каждому прошлись ещё одним циклом.

Comment: да, спасибо вам огромное! Это именно то что я имел в виду и именно то что мне необходимо.

Comment: @Webdev96 проверьте правильно ли делит массив, но должно быть всё верно